# Azure edit/change servicename DNS URL

Tags: azure, dns, azure-cloud-services

I have two VMs pointed to a Azure oldname.cloudapp.net url I want to change that without deleting VMs.

`Set-AzureService` does not change service name! It only changes label name and description.

I can create new cloud service, but how make my current two VMs point to new URL AND delete the old one?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename a `cloudapp.net`. You need to create a new service and redeploy:

- If `oldname.cloudapp.net` contains Virtual Machines, delete the existing virtual machines (but *not* the vhd's) from the old url and deploy them to the new url. The overall effect will be like turning off the VM's and turning them back on.
- If it contains web/workers, you just need to redeploy the package and configuration.

Note: In both cases, the new `cloudapp.net` will have a different external IP address.

Comment: I would also add that you shouldn't care about the .cloudapp.net name.  Ideally you have a custom domain name (ie. myapp.com) with a CNAME pointing to the .cloudapp.net name.  This way you can change your cloudapp.net name at any time and all you care about is updating your CNAME record.